# no puedo ver los atributos de una instancia de clase

Tags: python, clase, atributos, parámetros

En el código que muestro abajo no entiendo por qué dentro de la clase my_Gui a la cual le he pasado como argumento, en la parte del main, una instancia de la clase "coche", no puedo acceder a los atributos del objeto self.myCar, es decir a las propiedades make y "color" que es lo que quiero ver.

Este es el código. Ya perdonaréis si el fallo es demasiado simple. Estoy empezando con esto. Gracias.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class coche():
    def __init__(self, make, color):
        self.make = make
        self.color = color

    def imprime_coche(self):
        print(str(self.make) + str(self.color))


class my_Gui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, car):
        super().__init__()
        self.myCar = car

        # EN ESTA LINEA SI ESCRIBO self.myCar. NO PUEDO VEL LAS PROPIEDADES make y color y no entiendo por qué

        self.mi_window_principal = QMainWindow()
        self.mi_ui = Ui_my_template_class()  #
        self.mi_ui.setupUi(self.mi_window_principal)
        self.mi_window_principal.setWindowTitle("WINDOW TITLE")

    def f_show(self):
        self.mi_window_principal.showMaximized()


class Ui_my_template_class(object):
    def setupUi(self, my_template_class):
        my_template_class.setObjectName("my_template_class")
        my_template_class.resize(800, 600)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(my_template_class)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 220, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(my_template_class)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 390, 55, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(my_template_class)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(my_template_class)

    def retranslateUi(self, my_template_class):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        my_template_class.setWindowTitle(_translate("my_template_class", "my_template_class"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("my_template_class", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("my_template_class", "myLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mi_Aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myCoche = coche("Renault", "Negro")
    mi_ventana_principal = my_Gui(myCoche)
    mi_ventana_principal.f_show()

    sys.exit(mi_Aplicacion.exec_())
```

Comment: Tal como está, no consigo reproducir el error que comentas. Veo los atributos de `myCar` sin problemas. Intenta completar el código para que sea exáctamente como el que te da errorç. Otra cosa sobre el estilo: es norma aceptada que los nombres de las clases empiecen siempre por mayúsculas.

Comment: Ahora que me has dicho esto he hecho operaciones con los datos de la otra clase y funciona perfectamente. Lo que me ocurría es que el pyCharm al poner el self.myCar. me abre una lista de opciones en las que NO aparecen los atributos de la clase coche y es ahí donde yo me quedaba parado creyendo que no me vinculaba los atributos porque no estaba leyendo la clase porque algo estaba haciendo mal. Felizmente no es así, lo que me interesa que es el código está bien aunque me fastidia que el pyCharm no me enseñe los atributos de esa clase. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: PyCharm no tiene forma de presuponer qué es lo que pasas a `my_Gui` sin ejecutar el código o, al menos, hacer un exhaustivo análisis de cobertura, para lo que hay que darle tiempo suficiente. Pero puedes ayudarle usando [tipado gradual](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/). Añade el tipo esperado en la inicialización: `def __init__(self, car: Coche):`

Comment: Tipado gradual, no lo conocía, esa es la clave. Ahora sí que salen inmediatamente todos los atributos y métodos en el pyCharm. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Mira también la inferencia de tipos de pycharm. Yo no lo utilizo, pero lo he visto con intellij en otros lenguajes.